# Simple command-line app I/O in Dart

Tags: dart, keyboard-events, dart-io

Is there a way of taking single character (integer) keyboard inputs from the user and storing them to a variable in a Dart command-line app? I've tried something like:

```dart
Stream cmdLine = stdin
  .transform(new StringDecoder())
  .transform(new LineTransformer());

StreamSubscription cmdSubscription = cmdLine.listen(
  (line) => (choice = line);
  cmdSubscription.cancel(););
```

In an attempt to store a keyboard input into the variable 'choice' and many slight variations of this code but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can only read a whole line at a time - i.e. once enter is pressed.

Star this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7136).

**Updated:**

The readLine() function waits for a line of input from a user and returns it as a string.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

main() {
    print('1 + 1 = ...');
    readLine().then((line) {
        print(line.trim() == '2' ? 'Yup!' : 'Nope :(');
    });
}

Future<String> readLine() {
    var completer = new Completer<String>();

    var input = stdin
        .transform(new StringDecoder())
        .transform(new LineTransformer());

    var subs;
    subs = input.listen((line) {
        completer.complete(line);
        subs.cancel();
    });

    return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: That would be fine with me, just looking for the user to type a 1 or 2 then enter ;D

Comment: I've added an example that does this - give me a shout if it's broken.

Comment: Hhmm trying to use the function but the code seems to skip past the readLine call readLine().then((s) without waiting on input. Inside that call I'm trying to set a global variable choice equal to s so I have:

    readLine().then((s) {
      choice = s;
    });
    while (choice == 0) {
    
    }
    print('YOU ENTERED $choice');

trying to use the while loop to force a wait on input but still after entering anything and pushing enter it never ends up reaching the print statement. And if I remove the while loop it just hits the print without waiting on input. Am I implementing incorrectly?

Comment: Forgot to mention I initialized: "var choice = 0;" earlier on

Comment: Testing with print statements in different spots, I see the "choice = s;" part of the code inside the readLine call never gets reached, and I think the subs = input.listen((line) {
        completer.complete(line);
        subs.cancel();
    });
also never runs

Comment: Works for me ;) I've now posted a full example showing how to use it. It uses the dart Future api, have a look at this article. http://www.dartlang.org/articles/using-future-based-apis/