# Console application - StringDecoder stdin

Tags: dart, dart-io

The following or similar was shown for terminal input, however terminating input with ctl-d is not good. Is there another way to exit from this "loop"?

```dart
import "dart:io";

void main() {
  stdout.write("Enter Data : ");
  new StringDecoder().bind(stdin).listen((String sInput){});
////  Do something with sInput ............
}
```

Comment: when you say "not good", what do you mean?

Comment: @jdigital. I just want the "operator" to hit "enter" and then use the data entered.

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15440138/how-to-read-console-input-on-m3-dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can terminate a dart program by running the `exit` method when using dart:io

```
void exit(int status)
Exit the Dart VM process immediately with the given status code.

This does not wait for any asynchronous operations to terminate.
Using exit is therefore very likely to lose data.
```

[From the docs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io.html)

That code would go inside a check in the event handler in `listen`

Answer (score 1):

A few options come to mind.  First, you could use `takeWhile()` to set a 'done' condition:

```dart
new StringDecoder().bind(stdin)
  .takeWhile((s) => s.trim() != 'exit')
  .listen((sInput) {
```

That will use the same `onDone` handler (if one is set) when the user inputs the `EOF` character or types `exit` followed by the enter key.  You can have more flexibility by cancelling the subscription with `cancel()`:

```dart
void main() {
  stdout.write("Enter Data : ");
  var sub;
  sub = new StringDecoder().bind(stdin).listen((String sInput) {
    if (sInput.trim() == 'exit' || sInput.trim() == 'bye')
      sub.cancel();
    // Do something with sInput ............
  });
```

Cancelling the subscription doesn't close the Stream, so any `onDone` handler isn't called.

Of course, if you've got nothing left to do, you can always terminate with `exit(0)` [[1](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io.html#exit)].